# How do I exit a program in a try/except block in Python through a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, try-except

I am making the game [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html) in Python and I am nearing the end. Now, I am trying to end the program whenever the user guesses the word right but whatever I am trying, nothing is working. I tried doing `sys.exit()`, `quit()`, `SystemExit(1)`, etc, but still, nothing is working. Could you please help me solve this issue and help me end the code? Thanks.

Here is the area of my code where I need help:

```
    winRow = [32, 32, 32, 32, 32]
    if colorRow == winRow:
        print("YOU WON!")
        SystemExit(1)


    return board, colorList, colorRow, result


numList = ["FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD", "FOURTH", "FIFTH", "SIXTH"]
for x in range(len(numList)):
    z = True
    while z == True:
        try:
            guess = input(f"{numList[x]} GUESS  > ").upper()
            guess = list(guess)
            checkRight(guess, word, x+1)
            boardprint()
            z = False
        except:
            boardprint()
            print("Make sure your word is 5 letters")
```

Here is my full code:

```
import rich
from rich.text import Text
import random

    
testList = ["PRICE"]
word = random.choice(testList)


board = {
    6 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    5 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    4 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    3 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    2 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    1 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
}

colorList = {
    6 : [39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
    5 : [39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
    4 : [39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
    3 : [39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
    2 : [39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
    1 : [39, 39, 39, 39, 39] 
}

def boardprint():
    global board, colorList

    final = []
    for x in range(len(board)):
        spots = [f"\033[{col}m{board[x+1][idx]}\33[0m" for idx, col in enumerate(colorList[x+1])]
        l = ' '.join(spots)
        final.append(f"| {l} |")
    ansi_rich = Text.from_ansi('\n'.join(final))
    rich.print(ansi_rich)

    return colorList



guess = ""

result = "playing"

def checkRight(guess, word, row):
    global board, colorList

    GuessCheckDouble = {i:guess.count(i) for i in guess}
    WordCheckDouble = {i:word.count(i) for i in word}
    result = {key: GuessCheckDouble[key] - WordCheckDouble.get(key, 0) for key in GuessCheckDouble.keys()}
    updateRow = []
    colorRow = []

    for x in range(len(word)):
        if guess[x].upper() == word[x]: # green
            
            letter = guess[x]
            updateRow.append(letter)
            colorRow.append(32)

        elif guess[x].upper() in word and result[guess[x]] == 0: # yellow
            
            letter = guess[x]
            updateRow.append(letter)
            colorRow.append(33)
            
        else: # grey

            letter = guess[x]
            updateRow.append(letter)
            colorRow.append(30)

    

    board.update({row : [updateRow[0], updateRow[1], updateRow[2], updateRow[3], updateRow[4]]})
    colorList.update({row : [colorRow[0], colorRow[1], colorRow[2], colorRow[3], colorRow[4]]})

    winRow = [32, 32, 32, 32, 32]
    if colorRow == winRow:
        print("YOU WON!")
        SystemExit(1)


    return board, colorList, colorRow, result

word = word.upper()
word = list(word)


print("hello! welcome to \033[32;1mWORDLE\033[0m")
print("\tTry to guess a 5-letter word in 6 guesses or less.\n\t\tIf a letter is \033[32mgreen\033[0m, then it is in the right place,\n\t\tIf a letter is \033[33myellow\033[0m, then it is in the wrong place, \n\t\tif a letter is \033[30mgrey\033[0m, then it is the wrong letter.")
print()
boardprint()
print()

numList = ["FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD", "FOURTH", "FIFTH", "SIXTH"]
for x in range(len(numList)):
    z = True
    while z == True:
        try:
            guess = input(f"{numList[x]} GUESS  > ").upper()
            guess = list(guess)
            checkRight(guess, word, x+1)
            boardprint()
            z = False
        except:
            boardprint()
            print("Make sure your word is 5 letters")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System exiting exceptions (`KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, etc) do not inherit from `Exception`, so don't use a bare `except` which will catch all exceptions, catch `Exception` instead so that system exiting exceptions are not caught

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    # Only handles non-system exiting exceptions
    ...
```